# Hide other divs when clicking another div with the same class or clicking somewhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I want to make a list of divs, like that:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

When you click on a div.b, div.c (only from the same div.a parent) should have a .vis class added. When you click on another div.b it adds the class to its sibling (div.c) and removes the class from the last clicked div.c. When don't click div.b, but somewhere else, the .vis class is removed from every div.c.

```
window.onclick = function(window) {

    if(window.target.className === 'b'){

        $(".b").each(function() {

            $(".b").on("click", function(){
                $(this).siblings(".c").addClass("vis");
            })

        })

    } else {
        $(".c").removeClass("vis");
    }

}
```

The code above doesn't work as it should. I have to click 2 times to add the class (First it executes the function to check the target class and the second click adds the class).
When I click on another div.b the .vis class from the click before isn't removed (so I have a few divs with .vis class, but I should have only 1 at a time).
How can I make this work?

Comment: I would not advice you to have a click method defined inside another click method

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I know this isn't how it should look, that is why I'm posting here to get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'b'){
    // removing vis class from all c divs
        $('.a .c').removeClass('vis');
    // Add vis class to the sibling div 
    $(e.target).siblings().addClass('vis');
  }
  else {
  //When clicking outside of b remove vis class from all c div
  $('.a > .c').removeClass('vis');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.vis {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86ku05hp/

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
$('.a .b').click(function() {
  $(".c").removeClass("vis");
  $(this).next().addClass("vis")
})
```

When `.b` is clicked, it will remove class `vis` from all `.c`, and add it to the `.c` in connection to the clicked `.b`

**Demo**

```js
$('.a .b').click(function() {
  $(".c").removeClass("vis");
  $(this).next().addClass("vis")
})

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("b") && !$(e.target).parent().hasClass("b")) {
    $(".c").removeClass("vis");
  }
});
```

```css
.vis {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't 100% correct. When I click on something else (empty space, other divs, etc.) I want to remove the .vis class from all of the div.c elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let b = document.querySelectorAll(".b");
    let c = document.querySelectorAll(".c");
    
    b.forEach(elem => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        c.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("vis"));
        elem.nextElementSibling.classList.add("vis");
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.b {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.vis {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="a">
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: While answer is good, consider using the snippet tool on Stack Overflow snippet tool to display working examples of the code. This way we don't loose the example